# Correct length for WINDOWPLACEMENT struct

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I am working on an app which needs to get/set Win32 window placement information. I am using .NET Core 3.1, and Windows 10 1909. I have added a P/Invoke method and structs for GetWindowPlacement:

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public long left;
    public long top;
    public long right;
    public long bottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
{
    public uint length;
    public uint flags;
    public uint showCmd;
    public POINT ptMinPosition;
    public POINT ptMaxPosition;
    public RECT rcNormalPosition;
    public RECT rcDevice;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public long x;
    public long y;
}
```

I then call it like this:

```
var placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
placement.length = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(placement);
if (GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, ref placement))
{
    // do something with placement info
}
```

`Marshall.SizeOf` returns a length of 108 bytes, and the call appears to succeed, but afterwards the placement struct always has it's `length` value set to 44, and the `RECT` values are all 0. `flags`, `showCmd`, and the `POINT` values come through fine. I've tried hard-coding the `length` to other values like 112 or 120 bytes, or 0 bytes, but I always get the struct back with `length = 44` and no rectangles.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `<Windows.h>` the structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct tagWINDOWPLACEMENT {
    UINT  length;
    UINT  flags;
    UINT  showCmd;
    POINT ptMinPosition;
    POINT ptMaxPosition;
    RECT  rcNormalPosition;
#ifdef _MAC
    RECT  rcDevice;
#endif
} WINDOWPLACEMENT;
typedef WINDOWPLACEMENT *PWINDOWPLACEMENT, *LPWINDOWPLACEMENT;
```

So its size is `3*sizeof(UINT)+2*sizeof(POINT)+1*sizeof(RECT)` without `_MAC` defined, and plus one more `RECT` with `_MAC` defined.

So it is 44, and 60 on `_MAC` (see [What's with "#ifdef _MAC" in Windows header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2376478/2945027))

So you should define it without `RECT rcDevice`

Another mistake is that C# `long` is 8 bytes, you need `int` in `POINT` and `RECT`.

Fix both, and you'll have 44.

Comment: Yes, the `long` mismatch is what did me in. Thanks!