# PowerShell Add-Type Simple C# Structures -- One works and one doessn't

Tags: c#, powershell, pinvoke

I've had some success with p-Invoking some API functions, but now something seemingly simple has me stumped.

This code works:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class WPAPI1 {

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT {
        public long x;
        public long y;

        public POINT( long x, long y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    };
}
'@
```

Output and test:

```
PS > Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
>> using System;
>> using System.IO;
>> using System.Text;
>> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
>>
>> public class WPAPI1 {
>>
>>     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
>>     public struct POINT {
>>         public long x;
>>         public long y;
>>
>>         public POINT( long x, long y)
>>         {
>>             this.x = x;
>>             this.y = y;
>>         }
>>     };
>> }
>> '@
>>
WARNING: The generated type defines no public methods or properties.
PS > $p = [WPAPI1+POINT]::new(5,10)
PS > $p

x  y
-  -
5 10
```

But this code won't compile:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class WPAPI2 {

    StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT {
        public long left;
        public long top;
        public long right;
        public long bottom;

        public RECT(long left, long top, long right, long botton)
        {
            this.left   = left;
            this.top    = top;
            this.right  = right;
            this.bottom = bottom;
        }
    };
}
'@
```

Throwing the following errors:

```
Add-Type : c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(8) : Method must have a
return type
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(7) :
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(8) : >>>
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(9) :     public struct RECT {
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCo
   mpilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCo
   mmand

Add-Type : c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(8) : Identifier expected
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(7) :
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(8) : >>>
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(9) :     public struct RECT {
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCo
   mpilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCo
   mmand

Add-Type : c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(8) : ; expected
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(7) :
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(8) : >>>
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\3v2a5y04.0.cs(9) :     public struct RECT {
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCo
   mpilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCo
   mmand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. Compilation errors occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeComm
   and

PS >
```

Focusing on the first error: `Method must have a return type`, my internet searches aren't helping. Consturctors aren't supposed to need a return type, and I've triple-checked case and spelling of `RECT`.

I'm stumped. Please advise...

### Edit:

Fixed the missing `[` (thought my error had changed but it was getting late). After that, code produces different error:

```
Add-Type : c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\saoucata.0.cs(17) : Warning as Error:
Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\saoucata.0.cs(16) :         {
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\saoucata.0.cs(17) : >>>             this.left = left
; this.top = top ; this.right = right ; this.bottom = bottom;
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\saoucata.0.cs(18) :         }
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCo
   mpilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCo
   mmand

Add-Type : c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\saoucata.0.cs(17) : Use of possibly
unassigned field 'bottom'
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\saoucata.0.cs(16) :         {
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\saoucata.0.cs(17) : >>>             this.left = left
; this.top = top ; this.right = right ; this.bottom = bottom;
c:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\saoucata.0.cs(18) :         }
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCo
   mpilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCo
   mmand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. Compilation errors occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeComm
   and
```

I appreciate the help. Visually impaired here -- have to zoom in a lot -- can make one lose the "big picture", so to speak! :D

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo of a copy/paste issue but there's a missing [ in front of StructLayout. Also it's unrelated but a RECT is probably composed of int (long is 64 bit in.NET)

Comment: @SimonMourier That is the correct answer, and should be provided as such (versus a comment) so it can be marked Answered.

Comment: @Graham - I'd like Keith to confirm it's the problem he has.

Comment: @SimonMourier: Thanks. I think I lost the `[` at some point during copy & paste. Thought my error had changed but it was getting late & I was going batty. Now that that's fixed, getting "assignment" errors....

Comment: @SimonMourier: As for `long` vs. `int`, I was using this reference: [`RECT structure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect).

Comment: @SimonMourier: And some web page I've closed made me think `C++ long`  was also long in C#. But found [this thread about the `WindowPlacement` structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62582387/correct-length-for-windowplacement-struct) -- which is what I was butilding towards. `long` -> `int` everywhere and the funcdtions are working nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class WPAPI2 {

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT {
        public long left;
        public long top;
        public long right;
        public long bottom;

        public RECT(long left, long top, long right, long bottom)
        {
            this.left   = left;
            this.top    = top;
            this.right  = right;
            this.bottom = bottom;
        }
    };
}
'@
```

Note: "[" before StructuredLayout and "botto**n**" vs "botto**m**" in the RECT signature.

Comment: Thank you, Graham! I feel stupid, but now I can proceed adding code and generating more errors! :D  A second set of eyes is even more imprtant than usual since mine don't work so well!

Comment: No worries.  I wish Simon would have submitted an answer to get the reputation, as he spotted the initial issue first, but not going to twist anyone's arm to get it posted.

Comment: If RECT is the Win32 RECT structure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect, then it must be int (32-bit), not long (64-bit). You can use .NET Framework reference source as a good interop definitions input: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,3076